# How to tween text up and down, and make it react to touch events

Tags: actionscript-3, gsap

I have a Tweenlite animation in actionscript and I want to execute a method on Touch Event that would interrupt tweening. Actually it would pause it, execute method and then continue tweening.
I have no idea how to do that. Can someone help?

Thanks!

So, I know this doesn't work. My question is how to make it work.

```
package { 

imports... 

public class App extends Sprite {

private var textField:TextField = new TextField(220, 35, "Tap to flip the text!", "Roboto", 22, 0xf1f1f1, false);

public function App() {
    super();
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, textPlay);
}

private function textPlay(event:Event):void {
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, textPlay);

    textField.border = 1;
    textField.hAlign;
    textField.vAlign;

    textField.x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - textField.width / 2;
    textField.y = stage.stageHeight / 2 - textField.height / 2;

    addChild(textField);

    addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH, turn);

    down();
}

private function down():void {
    addEventListener(starling.events.Event.ENTER_FRAME, check);
    TweenLite.to(textField, 5, {y:(stage.stageHeight - textField.height)});
    up();
}

private function up():void {
    TweenLite.to(textField, 5, {y:0});
    down()
}

private function turn(event:TouchEvent):void {
    TweenLite.to(textField, 0, {rotation:180});
}

}
}
```

Comment: If you show your existing code I can make a better answer.

Comment: So where in your code should the tween pause?  right now you call `up` inside the `down` function, then `down` from the `up` function, which will create a stack overflow.  your code as posted will crash your application.

Comment: and in the `check` function, you add then remove an event listener which effectively does nothing.

Comment: thank you for confirming that I'm a noob. :D

Comment: I'm just trying to understand what you're trying to actually do.

Comment: I need text to go from top to bottom around and then there is touch event to rotate 180°.

Comment: So when it's rotating you don't want it to move up or down?

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I appreciate it. :)

Comment: it should move constantly up and down. only change is rotation on touch

Comment: Ok, I think I understand.  And what is the purpose of the `check` function?

Comment: my bad. I didn't delete it after last dead end in trying to solve this. I'll edit it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to store the tween in a variable so you can manipulate it later

```
var myTween:TweenLite = TweenLite.to(...);

function myTouchEventHandler(e:TouchEvent):void {
    myTween.pause(); //pause the tween
}

function someOtherFunction():void {
    myTween.resume(); //resume tweening from where it left off
}
```

---

### **EDIT**

Here is what I think you're trying to do (which doesn't have anything to do with pausing or stopping tweens)

```
package { 

imports... 

public class App extends Sprite {

    private var textField:TextField = new TextField(220, 35, "Tap to flip the text!", "Roboto", 22, 0xf1f1f1, false);

    public function App() {
        super();
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, textPlay);
    }

    private var moveSpeed:int = 2; //how many pixels to move the textField every frame

    private function textPlay(event:Event):void {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, textPlay);

        textField.border = 1;
        textField.hAlign;
        textField.vAlign;

        textField.x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - textField.width / 2;
        textField.y = stage.stageHeight / 2 - textField.height / 2;

        addChild(textField);

        addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH, turn);

        //this instead of using a tween, just use the enterframe method and move the textField up (or down) every frame
        addEventListener(starling.events.Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveText);
    }

    private function moveText(event:flash.events.Event):void {
        if(textField.y + moveSpeed > (stage.stageHeight - textField.height) || textField.y + moveSpeed < 0){
            moveSpeed *= -1; //change direction
        };

        textField.y += moveSpeed;
    }

    private function turn(event:TouchEvent):void {
        TweenLite.to(textField, 0, {rotation:textField.rotation == 180 ? 0 : 180}); //assuming you want to toggle 180 or 0, not just always set to 180
    }
}
}
```

If you still wanted to use a tween, then this would be the way: (using the onComplete parameter of tweenLite)

```
function up():void {
    TweenLite.to(textField, 5, {y:0, onComplete: down});
}

function down():void {
    TweenLite.to(textField, 5, {y:(stage.stageHeight - textField.height), onComplete: up});
}

function turn(event:TouchEvent):void {
    //need the overwrite property so it doesn't cancel the other tween on this same object
    TweenLite.to(textField, 0, {overwrite: 0, rotation:textField.rotation == 180 ? 0 : 180}); //assuming you want to toggle 180 or 0, not just always set to 180
}
```

OR, use `TweenMax` and set the `yoyo` property to true and just use one single tween.

Comment: I see what you mean. This is helpful, but I have tweenlite that is in process and then it has to stop on touch event.

So if I start TweenLite.to how can I make it stop on touch?

Comment: So do you want to stop or pause?  `myTween.kill()` will stop/destroy it.

Comment: OMG! I knew that was it!

Comment: Indeed it can (shown in the bottom of my answer), but there is no need to really.

Comment: Yes but this last part still has a problem of touch to rotate.

Comment: You have to set the `overwrite` property to `0`, otherwise the rotation overwrites the movement tween.  I'll add it in my answer.